# MPI point to point communication elapsed times

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, latency

In a basic approach at measuring elapsed time in a point to point (P2P) communication setting (own laptop in this case) using the following code, the resulting elapsed times are negative.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N_ITER 5

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int world_rank;
        int world_rank_count;

        MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank_count);

        int n = N_ITER;
        double ts = 0.0;

        while (n > 0) {
                if (world_rank == 0) {
                        ts = MPI_Wtime();

                        MPI_Send(&ts, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 1000 + n,
                                 MPI_COMM_WORLD);

                        MPI_Recv(&ts, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 1000 + n,
                                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

                        fprintf(stdout, "elapsed %.16f\n", ts);
                } else {
                        ts = 0.0;

                        MPI_Recv(&ts, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1000 + n,
                                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

                        /* sleep for 1 sec */
                        usleep(1000 * 1000);

                        ts = MPI_Wtime() - ts;
                        MPI_Send(&ts, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 1000 + n,
                                 MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                } 

                n = n - 1;
        }

        MPI_Finalize();

        return 0;
}
```

For instance,

```
$ mpicc -o bi.comm.elapsed.3 bi.comm.elapsed.3.c && mpirun -np 2 ./bi.comm.elapsed.3

elapsed 0.0000000000000000
elapsed -0.0000761619999998
elapsed -0.0000088069999999
elapsed -0.0001101540000001
elapsed -0.0000866199999994
```

Although this is not truly the way to estimate P2P latency, the purpose here is to learn and understand why such values are not above zero.

Comment: you make the incorrect assumption that `MPI_Wtime()` is some how global and monotonic accross tasks. It can only be used to calculate time differences on a given rank. Try adding `MPI_Wtime()` before entering the `while` loop, i let you figure out what is happening under the hood :-)